# Function problems?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a function without parameters but it does not work 
what is reason this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFBOV.png)

```
   CREATE FUNCTION x3()
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @ilk_isim varchar(50)
    declare @soy_isim varchar(50)
    declare @birlestir varchar(100)
    select @ilk_isim = adi from alici where id = 2
    select @soy_isim = adi from ilan_veren where id = 1
    select @birlestir = @ilk_isim+' '+@soy_isim

    return @birlestir
    end


select dbo.x3()
```

Comment: To start with: there are a lot of missing `;` in this code.

Comment: AND delimiters don't appear to be set AND you cannot declare user defined variables AND there is no varchar(max) in mysql or dbo.-- Are you sure this is a mysql question?

Comment: How can I get without parameters ?

Comment: @P.Salmon: also the use of `+` for string concatenation indicates SQL Server.

Comment: Your linked image indicates that you haven't actually created the function yet. You have 2 different SQL statements prepared in your editor (a `CREATE` statement and a `SELECT`) that you are trying to execute as one. When you run everything together as 1 statement, it is invalid syntax and you receive the error in your image. To get around this, execute each statement individually using SQL Server's default batch delimiter `GO` after your `end` keyword on a new line. This will create the function in one batch, and then execute another for the select. Alternatively run each statement separately

Comment: The image in the question indicates ms sql server, not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL Server. The `@` is necessary here for a variable declaration. `SELECT .. INTO ..` doesn't work with SQL Server, using assignment to variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION x3()
returns varchar(101)
begin
    declare @ilk_isim varchar(50);
    declare @soy_isim varchar(50);
    declare @birlestir varchar(101);

    select @ilk_isim = adi from alici where id = 2;
    select @soy_isim = adi from ilan_veren where id = 1;
    select @birlestir = CONCAT(@ilk_isim, ' ', @soy_isim);

    return @birlestir;
end

select dbo.x3()
```

Comment: but I changed it a bit

Answer (score -1):

You are merging MySql and Sql Server.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION x3() RETURNS VARCHAR(101)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ilk_isim VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE @soy_isim VARCHAR(50);
   SELECT adi INTO @ilk_isim FROM alici WHERE ID = 2;
   SELECT adi INTO @soy_isim FROM ilan_veren WHERE ID = 1;
   RETURN CONCAT(@ilk_isim, ' ', @soy_isim);
END;

SELECT x3();
```

Please refer to this link for information about FUNCTIONS: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-creating-stored-function/

This link for information about CONCAT: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php

This link for information about SELECT INTO VARIABLE: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-into-variable/

Comment: The picture in the question shows that the op uses ms sql server, not mysql.